# Get specific data from a PDF document Using pdfbox in java

Tags: java

I am new to this site. I decided to put here my problem because I block the design of the solution.

I'm trying to find a string in a PDF document and then retrieve the content it contains.

Here is an excerpt of pdf document:

```
1. Patchs et mises à jour logicielles

1.1 Installer les mises à jour, les correctifs et les logiciels de sécurité supplémentaires (non évalués)

Applicabilité du profil:

Level 1

Description:

Les correctifs périodiques sont publiés pour les logiciels inclus, soit en raison de défauts de sécurité, soit pour inclure des fonctionnalités supplémentaires ....
```

According to a search on the Internet, I found the "pdfbox" library which facilitates the extraction of the data and the browsing of the PDF document.

So I applied this library and I extracted the data from the FDF file. Here is my code:

```
public Boolean ExtractPDF() {

        try {
        String filename = "CIS_Ubuntu_12.04_LTS.pdf";
        String directory = "src/main/resources/static/pdf";
        String filepath = Paths.get(directory, filename).toString();

         System.out.println("*********** path file pdf "+filepath);

        PDDocument document = null;
        document = PDDocument.load(new File(filepath));
        document.getClass();
        if (!document.isEncrypted()) {

            PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
            stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
            PDFTextStripper Tstripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            String st = Tstripper.getText(document);
            System.out.println("********Text:***** " +st); // I have the text of the PDF document
                 }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }


       return true; 
  }
```

Thank you for helping me find the right solution,

Comment: And what is the specific problem ?

Comment: thanks, I do not know how to retrieve the big title (1. Patchs et mises à jour logicielles), the subtitle (1.1 Installer les mises à jour) and the contents of the paragraphs to store them in the DB.That is how to do a search of a string in a PDF document and retrieve their contents.

Comment: PDF doesn't have a feature to extract titles, unless it's a tagged PDF, and it almost never is, and PDFBox can't extract these anyway. You could only use heuristics if you know what to expect. But there is no magic solution that will work for all documents.

Comment: Thank you for your comment I will see how specific text.